# change bad url to happy url

Tags: php, url, seo

I saw other topics and applied but i cant resolved it.
you send me [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) this link!
but its diffrent between test.com/list/details.php?id=1 and test.com/details.php?id=1
why dont answer! and send me a link that dont work for my question

i want to change

```
test.com/list/details.php?brandname=abc
```

to

```
test.com/abc
```

with htaccess file or other way.

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: no that is for example test.com/details.php?id=1
but my question is test.com/test/details.php/brandid=abc
and i want to conver that to test.com/abc

Comment: The link shared to URL rewriting explains how to do it. You will simply need to adapt it to your specific use-case. It doesn't matter if it's `id=1` or `brandid=abc` that's being rewitten.

Comment: its diffrent between test.com/list/details.php?id=1 with test.com/details.php?id=1 |: |: